# Using MomentJS to turn a YYYY:MM:DD string to a day of week?

Tags: javascript, string, date, momentjs

So I'm using MomentJS for a project and need to convert or parse a string representing the date, to an actual day of the week.

For example,

I need 2015-07-24 to return a Friday or the number representing Friday for me.

Currently, I'm lost reading the moment docs and not sure it can do what I want it to do.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far

Comment: `moment("2015-07-24").day()` to get the day of the week - create a lookup object and youll be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like all you need is

```
var day = moment("1995-12-25").day(); // for the number
day = moment("1995-12-25").format('dddd')); // for the word
```

From here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/ and http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

You'll learn to read docs eventually :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

moment('2015-07-24').format('dddd');

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: Yes. Precisely! Thank you!